# Writing to a remote file: When does write() really return?

Tags: linux, file-io, io

I have a client node writing a file to a hard disk that is on another node (I am writing to a parallel fs actually).

What I want to understand is:
When I `write()` (or `pwrite()`), when exactly does the `write` call return?

I see three possibilities:

1. `write` returns immediately after queueing the I/O operation on the client side:
   In this case, `write` can return before data has actually left the client node (If you are writing to a local hard drive, then the write call employs delayed writes, where data is simply queued up for writing. But does this also happen when you are writing to a remote hard disk?). I wrote a testcase in which I write a large matrix (1GByte) to file. Without `fsync`, it showed very high bandwidth values, whereas with `fsync`, results looked more realistic. So looks like it could be using delayed writes.
2. `write` returns after the data has been transferred to the server buffer:
   Now data is on the server, but resides in a buffer in its main memory, but not yet permanently stored away on the hard drive. In this case, I/O time should be dominated by the time to transfer the data over the network.
3. `write` returns after data has been actually stored on the hard drive:
   Which I am sure does not happen by default (unless you write really large files which causes your RAM to get filled and ultimately get flushed out and so on...).

Additionally, what I would like to be sure about is:
Can a situation occur where the program terminates without any data actually having left the client node, such that network parameters like latency, bandwidth, and the hard drive bandwidth do not feature in the program's execution time at all? Consider we do not do an `fsync` or something similar.

EDIT: I am using the pvfs2 parallel file system

Comment: Which network filesystem? The rules for this are in the filesystem, and the system administrator may be able to choose between 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: I am writing to the pvfs2 parallel file system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3. is of course simple, and safe. However, a production quality POSIX compatible parallel file system with performance good enough that anyone actually cares to use it, will typically use option 1 combined with some more or less involved mechanism to avoid conflicts when e.g. several clients cache the same file.

As the saying goes, "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things and off-by-one errors".

If the filesystem is supposed to be POSIX compatible, you need to go and learn POSIX fs semantics, and look up how the fs supports these while getting good performance (alternatively, which parts of POSIX semantics it skips, a la NFS). What makes this, err, interesting is that the POSIX fs semantics harks back to the 1970's with little to no though of how to support network filesystems.

I don't know about pvfs2 specifically, but typically in order to conform to POSIX and provide decent performance, option 1 can be used together with some kind of cache coherency protocol (which e.g. Lustre does). For fsync(), the data must then actually be transferred to the server and committed to stable storage on the server (disks or battery-backed write cache) before fsync() returns. And of course, the client has some limit on the amount of dirty pages, after which it will block further write()'s to the file until some have been transferred to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can get any of your three options. It depends on the flags you provide to the `open` call. It depends on how the filesystem was mounted locally. It also depends on how the remote server is configured.

The following are all taken from Linux. Solaris and others may differ.

Some important `open` flags are `O_SYNC`, `O_DIRECT`, `O_DSYNC`, `O_RSYNC`.

Some important mount flags for NFS are `ac`, `noac`, `cto`, `nocto`, `lookupcache`, `sync`, `async`.

Some important flags for exporting NFS are `sync`, `async`, `no_wdelay`. And of course the mount flags of the filesystem that NFS is exporting are important as well. For example, if you were exporting XFS or EXT4 from Linux and for some reason you used the `nobarrier` flag, a power loss on the server side would almost certainly result in lost data.

Comment: Lets say I open the file using O_RDWR (and not any SYNC or O_DIRECT flags). What happens in this case?

Comment: @KVM: It depends on the system setup but I imagine they would use optimal settings which would include caching. In that case with no special flags the data will be cached in RAM both client and server side. It will be flushed to disk as time permits.

Comment: Agree, but can the program terminate while the data is still residing on the client? Or will the write() return only after the data is atleast stored away on a server buffer?

Comment: Operating system cache is independent of the running program. The program can exit and everything it wrote will remain in cache until it is written to disk. It is often smart to check the return value of `close()` because errors will be reported there.

Comment: @KVM: As to how this all applies to PVFSv2 I am not completely sure. I assume that you have read the PVFS documentation. I scanned it but I didn't see any guarantees about what is cached and what is not. You may need to read the source code for its Linux kernel module.